# Variables don't set in openOCD target event procedure

Tags: tcl, openocd

I am trying to read a value from memory and store it in a variable when the target is halted. I can read it successfully using **mdw *address*** but I cannot store it in a variable.

This is what I do:

```
$_TARGETNAME configure -event halted {
 echo "target halted"
 set var [mdw 0xec014008] # here mdw command executes but nothing is stored in var
 puts [format "var:%s\n" $var]
}
```

I get output like this:

```
  0xec014008: 00000001
     var:
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Possibly the procedure `mdw` is not returning any value as such.

Comment: it actually executes. I edited the output that I get. it seems like mdw executes first and nothing is stored in the variable. bit still don't know why.

Comment: It might be just printing the value instead of returning it...